# Oracle SQL - Delete subset of records based on criteria

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-delete

I have the following table

```
ITEM    LOCATION    EFFECTIVE_DATE  SELLING_RETAIL
00139259    11001   01-JUL-20           2
00139259    11001   08-OCT-19           1
00139259    11001   04-OCT-19           1
00139259    11001   01-JAN-18           2
00139259    11001   04-DEC-17           1
00139259    11001   02-MAR-17           500
```

I need to keep only three records for item, location and effective date based on the descending order.

so that I remain with:

```
ITEM    LOCATION    EFFECTIVE_DATE  SELLING_RETAIL
00139259    11001   01-JUL-20           2
00139259    11001   08-OCT-19           1
00139259    11001   04-OCT-19           1
```

and all the rest should be delete.

there are many item and location in the table, I need to keep 3 records for the combination of item/location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function to find the rows after the latest three and then correlate with the `DELETE` statement using the `ROWID` pseudo-column:

```sql
DELETE FROM table_name
WHERE ROWID IN (
  SELECT ROWID
  FROM   (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
             PARTITION BY item, location ORDER BY effective_date DESC
           ) AS rn
    FROM   table_name
  )
  WHERE  rn > 3
)
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE TABLE_NAME ( ITEM, LOCATION, EFFECTIVE_DATE, SELLING_RETAIL ) AS
SELECT '00139259', 11001, DATE '2020-07-01', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '00139259', 11001, DATE '2019-10-08', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '00139259', 11001, DATE '2019-10-04', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '00139259', 11001, DATE '2018-01-01', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '00139259', 11001, DATE '2017-12-04', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '00139259', 11001, DATE '2017-03-02', 500 FROM DUAL;
```

Then after the deletion:

```sql
SELECT * FROM table_name;
```

Outputs:

> | ITEM | LOCATION | EFFECTIVE_DATE | SELLING_RETAIL |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 00139259 | 11001 | 2020-07-01 00:00:00 | 2 |
> | 00139259 | 11001 | 2019-10-08 00:00:00 | 1 |
> | 00139259 | 11001 | 2019-10-04 00:00:00 | 1 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2cf208c7c524b1db8712746eb3420fc9)*

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by item, location order by EFFECTIVE_DATE desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 3;
```

This returns 3 rows for all item/location pairs.  If you have a single pair in mind, you can use:

```
select t.*
from t
where item = ? and location = ?
order by effective_date desc
fetch first 3 rows only;
```

Comment: How to i put delete with the same logic? It gives me error of "data manipulation operation not legal on this view"